# Invoking DynamicMethod on mscorlib generic type with .Net Standard generic parameter causes MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dynamic, .net-standard-2.0

So what's happening here?

Here's the backstory. I'm trying to integrate a .net standard library into a .net framework product. This .net framework product is using an old Microsoft.Practices framework which uses ObjectBuilder as the service container.

One thing that ObjectBuilder can't do that modern IoC containers can do is handle multiple implementations of the same service type and inject an IEnumerable<T> of the service type when requested. To handle this, I was manually going to add a List<T> and manually add each implementation when adding to object builder.

ObjectBuilder, when used in WebClientSoftwareFactory from Microsoft.Practices, uses IL to construct the objects for the container and inject dependencies into properties. So even if you add a singleton instance, it still tries to inject into properties of the instance using IL.

I had an error occur when trying to add a List<T> of a .Net Standard type into ObjectBuilder. I've been able to replicate what causes the error in a console application.

*This is the console application that is running on .net framework 4.7.2*

```
namespace ILTest
{
    class Program
    {
        delegate string Echo(string value);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WindowWidth = Console.WindowWidth * 2;

            EchoOn("1324");
            EchoOn(new List<string>());
            EchoOn(new NetStandardType());
            EchoOn(new List<NetStandardType>()); // this line fails
            EchoOn(new GenericNetStandardType<string>());
            EchoOn(new GenericNetStandardType<NetStandardType>());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void EchoOn<T>(T obj)
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            var value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var echo = CreateEchoMethodOn(obj);
            try
            {
                var echoed = echo(value);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine($"Successful il on {type.FullName}");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed il on {type.FullName}");
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        static Echo CreateEchoMethodOn(object obj)
        {
            var type = obj.GetType();
            var method = new DynamicMethod($"Echo_{type.FullName}", typeof(string), new[] { typeof(string) }, type);
            var il = method.GetILGenerator();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            return (Echo)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Echo));
        }
    }
}
```

*These are the classes in a .net standard 2.0 library*

```
namespace StandardLib
{
    public class NetStandardType
    {
    }

    public class GenericNetStandardType<T>
    {
    }
}
```

All of the DynamicMethods are successful except for the one on List<NetStandardType>. That one fails with a MissingMethodException.

- string

  - .net framework type
  - DynamicMethod successful
- List<string>

  - .net framework generic type
  - .net framework generic parameter
  - DynamicMethod successful
- NetStandardType

  - .net standard type
  - DynamicMethod successful
- List<NetStandardType>

  - .net framework generic type
  - .net standard generic parameter
  - **DynamicMethod fails**
- GenericNetStandardType<string>

  - .net standard generic type
  - .net framework generic parameter
  - DynamicMethod successful
- GenericNetStandardType<NetStandardType>

  - .net standard generic type
  - .net standard generic parameter
  - DynamicMethod successful

So, again, what is happening here? Is it a bug in DynamicMethod in.net framework?

Comment: I was able to repro this with the code you shared. However, I was also able to reproduce this with a type coming from the same assembly as the application.

This doesn't look like a .NET Standard specific issue. 

I _was_ able to make this work by replacing List<T> with Hashset<T>, so there is something special about the List<T>. I am going to dig deeper and see if I can figure out what is special about List<T> that prevents this from working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are seeing this behavior because of the complex way in which Code Access Security and the transparency rules work.

When you are using the List as the type owner for the DynamicMethod you are instructing the runtime to use the CAS options from that type. As you are using a user-defined type (on .NET 4) your type members are actually marked 'Critical' while the members on 'List' and the 'List' type are marked 'Transparent'.

Because you are trying to call 'Critical' code from a 'Transparent' type you get the error you mention.

I believe you could work-around this by marking the assembly that has your user type with this attribute:

```
[assembly: System.Security.SecurityTransparent]
```

While that should work, it is very difficult to say if that would have any unexpected consequences. I believe it would depend on your scenario. Please review [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/security-transparent-code-level-1) for more information.

Comment: The problem is that the types aren't necessarily mine. I did "solve" this issue by creating a new .net standard class. public class SafeList<T> : List<T> {}